# pg_restore failing to load dump

Tags: postgresql

Help! All of a sudden, I'm getting this error when trying to restore my local DB from a dump:

```
$ pg_restore --no-acl --no-owner --dbname my_db tmp/latest.dump
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while INITIALIZING:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout"
Command was: SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
```

Locally, I'm running postgresql 9.6.3. The dump comes from a server that is running 9.4. No known configuration changes to my machine since this command stopped working.

I understand that `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` was introduced in 9.6, but I should still be able to load a dump generated by 9.4. So what gives?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you used `pg_dump` from PostgreSQL 9.6 to create the dump of the 9.4 database.

If you want to create a dump that you can load into a 9.4 database, use `pg_dump` from PostgreSQL 9.4.